# rails elastic search with resources link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have enable elastic search in my rails application and queries like

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:q])
```

In view when I call it as loop getting error as `undefined method`model_name' for Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result:Class`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to post, class: 'list' do %>
       //...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**post** in the loop causes the error

But in normal condition it works fine.

How to get the resources url in elastic search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access to activerecord object collections,

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:q]).records
```